# How to start popupwindow from service in android?

Tags: android

I wish to create a floating button which will hover over the entire Android screen. When the button or hovering icon is clicked, it should open a small `popupwindow`.

I was able to create the hovering icon using service class however I am unable to launch `popupwindow`. Whenever I click the floating icon, the error log says:

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --  token null is not valid; is your activity running?


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

     /**
        * Created by sejal on 17-Oct-15.
    */
  public class bubble extends Service{

 PopupWindow popw;

private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView floatingFaceBubble;



public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    floatingFaceBubble = new ImageView(this);
    //a face floating bubble as imageView
    floatingFaceBubble.setImageResource(R.drawable.bubble);

    windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    //here is all the science of params
    final LayoutParams myParams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    myParams.x=0;

    // add a floatingfacebubble icon in window


    windowManager.addView(floatingFaceBubble, myParams);
    try{


        floatingFaceBubble.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             getpopuppwindow();

            }
        });



        //for moving the picture on touch and slide
        floatingFaceBubble.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            LayoutParams paramsT = myParams;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;
            private long touchStartTime = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //remove face bubble on long press
              /*  if(System.currentTimeMillis()-touchStartTime> ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() && initialTouchX== event.getX()){
             ////       windowManager.removeView(floatingFaceBubble);
             ////       stopSelf();
             //       return false;
             //   }  */
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        touchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        initialX = myParams.x;
                        initialY = myParams.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        myParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        myParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, myParams);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//(ViewGroup) floatingFaceBubble.findViewById(R.id.pop)


private void getpopuppwindow() {

    try {

        System.out.print("111111");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)bubble.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        System.out.print("222222");
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,(ViewGroup) floatingFaceBubble.findViewById(R.id.pop));

        System.out.print("333333");
        popw = new PopupWindow(layout ,300,100 ,true) ;
        System.out.print("444444");
        popw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}




@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: please show what you have tried.

Comment: I have added service .java which is being called from mainactivity  via intent

Answer (score 0):

You should not do these ui operations in your service class. Because after you show your button service instance will be removed and there is no context when you click the button. I think you should follow similar approach like below.

Service Class:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity);
activityIntent.putExtra("showPopup", true);
context.startActivity(activityIntent);
```

Activity Class:

```
onCreate(){

   boolean showPopUp = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("showPopup", false);
   if(showPopUp){

   // Show your popup here

   }

}
```